# How can I set a bot to self-deafen?

Tags: discord.js

I want my bot to join the room and self-deafen.

My code is:

```
client.on('ready', async () => {
    console.log(`Logged in ${client.user.tag}`)
    const voicechannel = client.channels.cache.get("869738167576723506");
    voicechannel.join();
    voicechannel.setSelfdeaf(true)
})
```

The error I'm getting is:

> TypeError: `voicechannel.setSelfMute` is not a function

Comment: This can’t be your current error. This code doesn’t show `setSelfMute`. It shows `setSelfdeaf`

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.setSelfMute()` is method of `voiceState` not `voiceChannel` so to using it you need to get voiceState after connected

```js
client.on('ready', async () => {
    console.log(`Logged in ${client.user.tag}`)
    const voicechannel = client.channels.cache.get("869738167576723506");
    await voicechannel.join();
    voicechannel.guild.me.voice.setSelfdeaf(true)
})
```

more docs: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=setSelfDeaf

Answer (score 0):

There is no `VoiceChannel.setSelfdeaf` function in discord.js as shown [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel). Use this instead

```js
const voicechannel = client.channels.cache.get("...");
    await voicechannel.join();
voicechannel.guild.me.voice.setSelfDeaf(true)
```